# TortoiseGit: How can I see a list of commits that are about to be pushed

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisegit

I have merged in some commits from different branches into my "develop" branch and I'm now ready to push them to the remote branch.

In TortoiseGit, is it possible to view a list of items that are about to be pushed?

`"Check for Modifications"` is not showing me anything, as the changes are coming from branches.

`"Show Log"` is also showing me a chronological list of all changes. I rather just see a simple list of items that are queued to be pushed.

I hope I'm making sense.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use "Sync Dialog"
Right click the repository folder, choose "Sync"

In "Out commits" tab, you will see a list of commits to be pushed to the remote.

Switch to "Out ChangeList" tab, you will see a list of changed files relative to the remote version.

If "Out commits" is empty or "Out ChangeList" tab does not appear, specify "remote branch" explicitly in the combo box. 
Then "Out commits" list will load and "Out ChangeList" tab will appear.
This may happen if current branch does not have a "remote-tracking branch".

"Pull Dialog" has no such info.

Comment: In the latest version of TortoiseGit, (1.8.16.0) the menu item is now "Git Sync...". The "Out Commits" tab is the default view. (Great answer - I was expecting to find this somewhere in the push dialog, but it's not.)

Comment: If the branch you're pushing does not exist, it seems picking the parent branch (assuming it's in the remote) gives what's needed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you have a way to specify this in TortoiseGit, but I think a command similar to this is what you want:

```
$ git log origin/master..master
```

Comment: Hey Paul. I'm a little new to Git. When I run your command, it doesn't give me anything. (running git log by itself gives me everything)

Comment: You're right. I messed-up the syntax. Try with the new command from my answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks, Paul!  I'm on a team that uses TortoiseGit, so I was interested in the original question.  But I prefer the terminal, so this did the trick!